# There's too much duplicate advice on how to ask questions (and to answer them)

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

These two pages are almost identical:

1. [/help/how-to-ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
2. [/questions/how-to-ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Except for some *little differences*.  Help center links to 1, the magic link `[ask]` points to 2. There are "related articles" in the sidebar of 2, but the sidebar of 1 is filled with links to other Help Center articles. There's a search bar in 2, but not in 1.

I  vote to close one of these pages as a duplicate of the other.

Same story with answering: one page in Help Center, one linked from `[answer]` magic link.

1. [/help/how-to-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)
2. [/questions/how-to-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: Test: [ask] and [answer]. Yes, both redirect. Embedded search bar has been replaced with a link to `/search`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/questions/how-to-ask` will be redirecting to `/help/how-to-ask`.

`/questions/how-to-answer` will be redirecting to `/help/how-to-answer`.

With you in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly, we need a top-level /how-to-ask page that randomly redirects to one of these existing pages. Then we can just link to *that*.

...Or we could figure out how to embed that search widget into a normal /help center page, which is the primary reason /questions/how-to-ask is still separate.

Until then, they'll remain slightly different pages with slightly different purposes.

Comment: I was updating as you answered: same duplication happens with "how to answer". There's no search bar there... Also, the magic link [ask] can only be posted *after* the question is asked. Too late to direct to the search bar then.

Comment: I forgot /questions/how-to-answer existed... Yeah, that one should definitely just be a redirect.

Comment: Seems like "How to embed a search widget into a help center page" would be a good question for Stack Overflow.